# notepad++ как в строке стелать замену, пропустив определенное содержимое

Tags: xml, notepad++, замена

Например. Имеем строку 0,5
Нужно сделать <weight="Вес товара в упаковке, кг">0,5. И таких строк в файле 1000,
Нужно, что бы само значение параметра не изменялось, а оставалось таким как в файле, а сам тег изменился. Заранее спасибо
Сама структура такая,

```
<param name="Длина кабеля, м">1.2</param>
<param name="Ширина, мм">120</param>
<param name="Глубина, мм">25</param>
<param name="Вес товара в упаковке, кг">0.05</param>
<param name="Объем, м3">0.00036</param>
<param name="Высота, мм">120</param>
<param name="Вес товара без упаковки, кг">0.03</param>
```

Нужно что бы остальные param оставались без измененний.

Comment: Замените param name на weight, а потом param на weight - всё делать ГЛОБАЛЬНО

Comment: непонятно, что должно измениться, что должно остаться, что должно пропуститься.

Comment: [param name] -> [weight]  потом [param] -> [weight]